# SSH tunneling: connect_to localhost port 22: failed

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, fedora

I want to connect from my computer to a remote computer using a middle server(u port forwarding). I run this command on remote computer:

```
ssh -R 9300:localhost:22 user@middleserver
```

and this one on my system:

```
ssh remoteuser@middelserver -p 9300
```

But I get this error on my system:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

this is the log of remote computer:

```
debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen localhost port 9309, originator xxx.xxx.xx.xx port 21470
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: connect_next: host localhost ([::1]:22) in progress, fd=7
debug2: fd 7 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: fd 7 is O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 7 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [xx.xx.xx.xx]
debug1: confirm forwarded-tcpip
debug3: channel 1: waiting for connection
debug1: channel 1: connection failed: Connection refused
debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: connect_next: host localhost ([127.0.0.1]:22) in progress, fd=8
debug2: fd 8 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: channel 1: waiting for connection
debug1: channel 1: connection failed: Connection refused
connect_to localhost port 22: failed.
debug2: channel 1: zombie
debug2: channel 1: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 1: free: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, nchannels 2
debug3: channel 1: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r2 i0/0 o0/0 fd 4/5 cc -1)
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 9):

*( the error you report is indicative of a problem in step1 below )*

First of all, do as the above poster mentioned: add `GatewayPorts yes` into /etc/ssh/sshd_config
and change your ssh -R line to

```
ssh -vvv -R *:9300:localhost:22 user@middleserver
```

*(remove -vvv after we get this working  )*

*Setting the bind address to * will forward connections on any interface and not just loopback ('lo' which includes 127.0.0.1 ==  localhost ).  `ifconfig` lists the interfaces.. i.e.  eth0, lo, and wlan0.*

If that doesn't work troubleshoot:

**Step 1)**  Make sure you are allowed to ssh into your remote machine:

On the remote machine itself try:

```
ssh localhost
```

If it says connection refused then you have to enable ssh on that machine.

If that succeeds, type `ifconfig` and note the local "inet 192.168.xxx.yyy" address.

**Step2)** try SSH from local machine

Next go to a machine on the same local network as your remote machine and try to ssh into your remote machine: `ssh mylgoinID@192.168.xxx.yyy`

If that doesn't succeed then check your remote machine's firewall ( see below ).

If that succeeded then

**Step 3)**  Try ssh from middleman machine

log into the middleman machine and try an ssh connection directly from there. In the above case you've run `ssh -R *:9300:localhost:22 middleuser@middleserver` on the remote machine so you need to log in to the middlemachine and run:  `ssh remoteuser@localhost -p 9300`

If that succeeds then the problem may be with a firewall on your server:

Before messing with iptables check and see if you've got a firewall manager in use. For example check if "ufw" is in use: `sudo ufw status` .  It would be much easier to use ufw than to mess with iptables directly.

`iptables -L` and check if port 9300 is open ( this will involve some research of iptables.. it's NOT straightforward). Cheat: If port 9300 is listed next to http and in a similar way then check if http is open. If 9300 is listed below then it may not be reached if a "deny all"-type directive is listed before it.
It also may be listed as a named port. `cat /etc/services | grep 9300` however doesn't bring up a name in this case

**Step 4)** Try your login again:

```
ssh remoteuser@middleserver -p 9300
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `sshd` on your middle server has not got the `GatewayPorts` configuration option set to yes (default is no view `man 5 sshd_options`) then you will have to specify a bind address on your forwarding:

```
ssh -R *:9300:localhost:22 user@middleserver
```

(you can specify the IP address of your local machine to make that more restrictive).

Without that only the loopback device is forwarded on middleserver.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my problem was much simpler than the OP's. I just had to do this:

`sudo apt install openssh-server`

in the remote computer.